# Angular, idiomatic string replacement?

Tags: angularjs

For some condition, I would like replace a String in my model when displaying it in html. I could do this my modifying my model, but is there a more idiomatic option? Possibly this should be done with a filter?

```
  <tr ng-repeat="i in ctrl.data" >
      <td>
         <div ng-show="i.category == 'default'">
             none
         </div>
         <div ng-show="i.category != 'default'">
            {{ i.category }}
         </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ i.category == 'default' ? 'none' : i.category }}
```

Or, if you have that in several places, use a filter.